# Haskell Servant and streaming

Tags: haskell, amazon-s3, servant

I am trying to add a functionality to my `servant` server that would get a file from Amazon S3 and stream it back to the user.
Because files can be big I don't want to download them locally and then serve them to clients, I'd rather prefer to stream them directly from S3 to clients.

I use `Amazonka` for what I do with S3 and I can get a stream for an S3 file as a `Conduit` sink.

But now I don't know how to get from `Sink` to `EitherT ServantErr IO a`.

Can anyone explain me how to do it or show me some example of how it can be done?

Comment: There's currently a PR in Servant for adding "Stream endpoint support". https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/pull/836

Comment: Just to update this search-engine-friendly question: Servant supports a [Stream module](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.18/servant-0.14.1/Servant-API-Stream.html) now.

Answer (score 4):

The is nothing in Servant to do this out of the box, however all the needed parts are available.

Before we begin, I guess that if you can stream to a Sink, that means you have a source (the [`gorsBody`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-4.2/amazonka-s3-1.3.7/Network-AWS-S3-GetObject.html#v:gorsBody) of [`GetObjectResponse`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-4.2/amazonka-s3-1.3.7/Network-AWS-S3-GetObject.html#t:GetObjectResponse) is a [`RsBody`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-4.2/amazonka-core-1.3.7/Network-AWS-Data-Body.html#t:RsBody), which is a Source)

First of all, Servant provides us with the possibility to add support for new return types, by creating a new instance of [`HasServer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.4.4.6/docs/Servant-Server-Internal.html#t:HasServer), so we could serve a `EitherT ServantErr IO (Source ...)` and have it stream.

To create that instance, we must implement `route :: Proxy layout -> Server layout -> RoutingApplication`. `Server layout`, in this case, just means `EitherT ServantErr IO layout`, `layout` being the source we want to server, so it's the function that returns a source (and may fail with an HTTP error).

We have to return a [`RoutingApplication`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-conduit-3.0.0.3/docs/Network-Wai-Conduit.html), which is (in continuation style) a function that takes a `Request` and returns a `RouteResult Response`, which means either an unmatched route error, or a response. Both `Request` and `Response` are standard wai, not Servant, so we can now look at the rest of the ecosystem to find how to implement it.

Fortunately, we don't have to go far: [`Network.Wai.Conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-conduit-3.0.0.3/docs/Network-Wai-Conduit.html) contains just what we need to implement the `route` function: `responseSource` takes a status value, some response headers and your source and gives you a `Response`.

So, that is quite a lot of work to do, but everything we need is there. Looking a the [source of the instance `HasServer * (Get ...)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.4.4.6/docs/src/Servant-Server-Internal.html#line-346) might help.

Comment: I think adding an explanation/reference for how to do this at the WAI level would be good in order to understand how this fits into the servant level.  For me it isn't clear what consumes what  `route` returns and how to think about the continuation style setup here.