# Streaming from S3 bucket using Amazonka with Servant

Tags: haskell, amazon-s3

I'd like to be able to stream S3 bucket object contents via Servant as the response body.

I'm having issues getting MonadResource instance missing for Handler:

```
src/Servant/Streaming/Example.hs:29:3: error:
    * No instance for (MonadResource Handler)
        arising from a use of `runAWS'
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: runAWS env conduits
      In the expression:
        do env <- newEnv Discover
           runAWS env conduits
      In an equation for `server':
          server
            = do env <- newEnv Discover
                 runAWS env conduits
   |
29 |   runAWS env conduits
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have made a repository to reproduce: https://github.com/domenkozar/servant-streaming-amazonka

`servant-streaming-server` handles `ResourceT` for `Stream (Of BS.ByteString) (ResourceT IO) ()`  https://github.com/plow-technologies/servant-streaming/blob/master/servant-streaming-server/src/Servant/Streaming/Server/Internal.hs#L77-L79

but since I'm using Amazonka I also need to make sure MonadResource for Handler is taken take in that bracket. It's not clear to me how to do that.

My understanding is that using `enter`/`hoistServer` this won't work since resources would be cleaned up too soon (before streaming).

Notes:

- This builds upon question asked in 2016: [Haskell Servant and streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974257/haskell-servant-and-streaming)
- Servant part is implemented via https://github.com/plow-technologies/servant-streaming/pull/2/files

## Edits

1. **EDIT: I've since replaced `$$` with `$$+-`**
2. **EDIT2: I've resolved Conduit specific errors, now fighting with MonadResource**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with

```
server :: Server API
server =  do
  env <- newEnv Discover
  res <- runInternalState (runAWS env conduits) st
  return (res >> liftIO (closeInternalState st))
```

https://github.com/domenkozar/servant-streaming-amazonka/commit/c5fad78dd7bf733cecb8790035105c819d5f5ae9